# Python: MySQLdb and "Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib"

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard

### The setup...

Trying to set up a clean Mac os X 10.6 install to develop python/django and I didn't remember running into this on 10.5.

After installing MySQL from the installer on `mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg` I ran

```
$ sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

and it seemed to go smoothly (output below)

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz (70Kb): 70Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
    warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    In file included from _mysql.c:36:
    /usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:325:1: warning: "SIZEOF_SIZE_T" redefined
    In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:9,
                     from pymemcompat.h:10,
                     from _mysql.c:29:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pymacconfig.h:33:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
    In file included from _mysql.c:36:
    /usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:419:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
    In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                     from pymemcompat.h:10,
                     from _mysql.c:29:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:803:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
    gcc-4.2 -Wl,-F. -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.so -arch x86_64
    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
    warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
Successfully installed MySQL-python
Cleaning up...
```

after this I tried:

```
$ python -c "import MySQLdb"
```

and it crapped out on me with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

### So on to my question...

What did I do wrong?/What else do I need to do?

Googling (and searching here) for this returns a lot of results getting this error message with Ruby not too many with Python tho.

Comment: use libmysqlclient.16.dylib for 10.5 instead

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`_mysql.so` refers to `libmysqlclient.16.dylib`. That is, the shared library that serves as the bridge between Python and the MySQL client library, `_mysql.so`, refers to the dynamic library for the MySQL client library, and that library cannot be loaded for some reason.

Questions you need to answer:

- Is there a `libmysqlclient.16.dylib` anywhere on your system? If not, you need to install
  the MySQL client software.
- If so, is the directory containing that library in your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting? If not,
  try adding it.
- If so, you'll have to ensure that the `libmysqlclient.16.dylib` file is not corrupt. My
  copy, installed in `/opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib`, courtesy of
  MacPorts, has MD5 signature `c79ee91af08057dfc269ee212915801a` and is 1,462,376 bytes in size. What does your copy look like?

Comment: Thanks very much Brian! My copy is at /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib, is 3,787,328 bytes and has an MD5 sig 9007ca637b74fd2b6c91c681cd4f22b0 so it's definitely different... But my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was empty, adding /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/ to it seems to have gotten me running again. Is there a reason the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was blank before this?

Comment: It's empty by default, I believe. Mine's empty, too, but I haven't actually tried to load the mysql library in Python for awhile. Take a look at the man page for `dyld` (`man dyld`), and look at the documentation for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Snow Leopard 10.6.6, w/Xcode4 (no PPC suport), I ended up having to add DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to my bash profile as so: ``export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH``. Never had to do that in previous installs. I hate how old and clunky this package it.

Comment: The suggestion to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH via export was the final piece for me.  Setting it with << DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=... >> didn't work.  This whole process was beyond annoying.

Comment: In Unix Bourne shell-like shells (such as `bash`), shell variables are local by default; that is, they are not put into the environment, but kept local to the process. The `export` keyword marks a variable as "exported to the environment". Thus, the linker (a subprocess to the shell) can actually see the variable. Just setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, without exporting it, means it's only local to that shell--and, thus, no help in solving this problem.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, and setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH fixed it.  Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: I had this problem too.  When in the world will that MySQL-Python package be updated and brought up to par?

Comment: @BrianClapper What client software are you talking about? Sequel Pro?  Or is there somthing from MYSQL.org that I am not seeing? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, but adding DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to my bash_profile or the etc/profile didn't help. I'm on OSX 10.8

Comment: `locate libmysqlclient.16.dylib
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql51/5.1.71/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib`

Comment: How do I check the MD5 signature of libmysqlclient.16.dylib?

Comment: Could you please also help me to solve given issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987782/facing-issue-while-configuring-mysql-with-apache-airflow-in-hadoop

Answer (score 97):

Just set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` after running `pip install` or `easy_install`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

Should do the job assuming your MySQL installation lives under `/usr/local/mysql`.

Comment: This fix worked for me but I have to do it every time I try to start up django. Is there a place where I can set this (save it in a file) that will make it a permanent setting?

Comment: @thomallen if you use `virtualenv` you could set/unset it in your  `bin/activate` script, otherwise I would recommend `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: `which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql` so my path should be `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin/mysql` right?

Comment: @Ava this is most likely a symbolic link only. Check where it is pointing `ls -l \`which mysql\`` and most likely you will find a **lib** folder there like `/usr/local/mysql/lib/`

Answer (score 42):

After easy_install, I create a soft link that solved the problem

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Comment: I have no idea what this did but it fixed my problem when all else failed! My humble thanks to you!!

Comment: best and simplest solution

Comment: This was the only one which worked for me too, tried everything else.

Comment: creating softlink solved my problem too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution is required for the more recent versions of Mac OS as they limit the directories the OS will search for dynlibs.

Answer (score 8):

It can also crop up if your MySQL client is newer than your MySQL-python package.  In my case, I had a libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib on my machine, but not a libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib.  Running `pip search mysql` revealed

> MySQL-python              - Python
>   interface to MySQL   INSTALLED: 1.2.3 
>   LATEST:    1.2.3c1

and running `pip install --upgrade MySQL-python` fixed my problem.

Comment: This fixed the same problem as the above dynlib hack did. Seems like the default version that's installed with pip install MySQL-python is 1.2.3, not the latest version 1.2.3c1. To get the latest version use: pip install MySQL-python==1.2.3c1

Comment: Great catch, this was my issue. It's worth mentioning that --upgrade didn't actually seem to upgrade it properly, whereas using install MySQL-python==[latest version] did

Comment: I had the same issue as @G.Moore  --upgrade didn't seem to catch the new .dylib reference.  
`pip uninstall MySQL-python && pip install MySQL-python` seems to work as well.

Answer (score 8):

On my setup (mysql 5.7.x from brew, pyenv), I had a newer lib file `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`. What worked was to `pip uninstall MySQL-python` and `pip install MySQL-python`.

Comment: Also try `pip --no-cache-dir install MySQL-python` in case there's cache.

Answer (score 7):

On the latest version of **MySQL 5.7.9** it's no support from `MySQL-python` and I used the `PyMySQL` library instead. Also I added in `manage.py` (in Django project) these lines to emulate API of MySQL-python:

```
try:
    # load MySQLdb interface emulation
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who need - or have - both MySQLdb & PyMySQL installed (in my case, I needed to have both installed because I use PyMySQL to connect to my local MySQL instances, and MySQLDb for remote/live instances):

Be sure you're using the right URI scheme. To access the local instances:

```
LOCAL_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@hostname/dbname'
```

and for live:

```
REMOTE_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqldb://username:password@hostname/dbname'
```

Making this distinction solved the issue for me