# MySQL Django Setup

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

I'm setting up a MySQL database with Django.

python manage.py runserver.

Worked, then I started editing my database in summertime.settings.py [summertime is the site name]

here is my user:

user: TestUser
password: password
host: 127.0.0.1

all privileges

My MAMP is set to port: 3306

here is my settings.py

[image]

When I run $ python manage.py syncdb I recieve the following errors:

[image]

thanks

Comment: -1 for unreadable screenshots instead of simply pasting the text.

Comment: You can click on the screenshots for high quality images. I don't care about points, but just FYI

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install the MySQLdb driver

`pip install mysql-python`

Comment: Tried that, and returned ----> Referenced from: /Users/msmith/Documents/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: You might need to install the MySQL development libraries for your system

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have in my pip freeze: MySQL-python==1.2.4

Comment: There are a few questions on SO about this issue e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559699/python-mysqldb-and-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509104/python-and-mysql-on-mac-os-x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730787/python-import-mysqldb-error-mac-10-6