# django server runerror about mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

first try django ,when I do './manage.py runserver' it shows:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have set default database of mysql and I installed mysql-Python dev.No idea what's going on.Somebody help...

Comment: What is in settings.py for your database?

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'books',   
        'USER': 'root',  
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQLdb problems in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109731/mysqldb-problems-in-django)