# link to libmysqlclient in IDLE

Tags: python, mysql, python-idle

I built/installed MySQL-python successfully; set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"` in `.bash_profile` (OS X Lion).  When I execute python from the command line and import MySQLdb, everything is fine.

But when I try to import MySQLdb in IDLE, I get the following:

```
ImportError:
dlopen(/Users/mstath/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so,
2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib Referenced from:
/Users/mstath/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
Reason: image not found
```

I would like to know if there is something I could configure for IDLE to be able to look in `/usr/local/mysql/lib/` to find libmysqlclient.

Installed Python/IDLE through python.org installer; no package managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely launching IDLE via the `IDLE.app` application bundle, for example, by double-clicking on the IDLE icon.  On OS X, GUI apps launched this way do not use a shell, like bash, and thus `.bash_profile` is not executed for them.  While there are other ways to work around this, the simplest way in this case is to launch IDLE from a shell command line in a terminal window rather than from `IDLE.app`.  Something like this should work if you used the default install options:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/idle3   # for idle3.x
```

or

```
$ /usr/local/bin/idle    # for idle2.x
```

You can also use a specific version number if you have multiple Python versions installed locally:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/idle3.2
```

Comment: Another, better option is to workaround the broken `mysql` install by using `install_name_tool` to put the correct absolute path to the dylib in `_mysql.so` as described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730787/python-import-mysqldb-error-mac-10-6  Then you can dispense with having to set the environment variable at all.