# Error configuring django with python-mysql in Mac OS 10.6.6

Tags: python, mysql, django, osx-snow-leopard, mysql-python

My Setup:

- Mac OS 10.6.6 - x86_64
- MySQL 5.5.8
- Python 2.7.1
- Django 1.2.5
- mysql-python installed via easy_install

My situation:

I've been struggling to get my setup to work. The problem is with the mysql-python interface. Originally, I was getting a similar problem (to the one I'm having with Django) doing an import statement in python:

```
import MySQLdb
```

But I read this [question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559699/python-mysqldb-and-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib) that proved successful in fixing it.
I installed django and it works great but it is having problems with the mysql interface.
When I fire the Terminal and type:

```
>> python manage.py dbshell
```

the following error is generated:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 11, in 
>       execute_manager(settings)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 438, in execute_manager
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 379, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 261, in fetch_command
>       klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 67, in load_command_class
>       module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dbshell.py", line 4, in 
>       from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line 77, in 
>       connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in **getitem**
>       backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
>       return import_module('.base', backend_name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in 
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/adogc45/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/adogc45/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
>     Reason: image not found

Now, I don't understand why importing the module in Python doesn't raise an error, but using the mysql interface in django does.

BTW, my settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
```

Also, the image actually exits in .../MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp

So, I have NO idea about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks to Peter and elithrar for pointing out two things I was missing (see the answers below). These solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

or:

```
pip install MySQL-python
pip install --upgrade MySQL-python
```

Helped me within a virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which I solved for the development program by including this line in my .bash_profile file (the magic file in my ~ directory which runs the shell):
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
where the offending libmysqlclient.16.dylib is in that directory.

However, when I try to run this within Apache as a python wsgi module Apache cannot find the libmysqlclient.16.dylib no matter what I do.  I have tried 
sys.path.append('/usr/local/mysql/lib')
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/mysql/lib'
no luck...
seems Apache does not read this environment variable, nor does python in this context (where it is not reading my .bash_profile file)... help!!!

Comment: Hi thanks, I had to export that path in my .bash_profile too!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

Instead of just `mysql`, if you're running Django 1.2.5.

Comment: I'd also suggest installing [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) instead of easy_install, since it can be a little more reliable.

Comment: Hi thanks! I changed 'mysql' to 'django.db.backends.mysql' for it to work.