# Python 2.7 and MySQLDB: Image not found (OSX)

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-2.7

I've just installed MySQL on my 10.10.1 MAC, and I'm trying to link it to Python. However I get this error when I'm trying to import the package.

```
  import MySQLdb as mdb
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ME/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ME/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I have no idea what "Image not found" means, or how to solve this.

MySQL is connected to the server in the background, and I installed the package through the terminal window using: `easy_install MySQL-python`

Any suggestions on where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Check where your `_mysql.so` is linking to:

```
otool -L /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

In my case I built the mysql source in `/tmp/` and once
`tmp` cleaned up my `dylib` went away. I never re-linked to a
reliable location like  `/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib` where
my mysql libraries live (because I copied them here after the build).

So I went back and rebuilt everything and made sure to run the command to 
update the package link to the correct `dylib`:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change <temp file location>/mysql-5.5.29/libmysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library//lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

I followed the setup found here:
http://dreamconception.com/tech/how-to-install-mysqldb-mysql-python-on-mamp/

**NOTE**: That I didn't need to do the step regarding changing the `configure.cmake`
file. When I looked at the `configure.cmake` file it made sense to me so I ran
it as-is and it worked.

Also note your `libmysqlclient.<num>.dylib`  might be something different so
do a `find  . -name "libmysqlclient.*.dylib"` to get the right one

Now re-run the `otool` command and see that the linking was updated.

References (and other solutions):

- [Python import MySQLdb error - Mac 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730787/python-import-mysqldb-error-mac-10-6/4731333#4731333)
- http://dreamconception.com/tech/how-to-install-mysqldb-mysql-python-on-mamp/

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem can be found in this link [Python: MySQLdb and "Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559699/python-mysqldb-and-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib)

> > _mysql.so refers to libmysqlclient.16.dylib. That is, the shared library that serves as the bridge between Python and the MySQL client library, _mysql.so, refers to the dynamic library for the MySQL client library, and that library cannot be loaded for some reason.
> >
> > Questions you need to answer:
> >
> > - Is there a libmysqlclient.16.dylib anywhere on your system? If not, you need to install the MySQL client software.
> > - If so, is the directory containing that library in your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH setting? If not, try adding it.
> > - If so, you'll have to ensure that the libmysqlclient.16.dylib file is not corrupt. My copy, installed in /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib, courtesy of MacPorts, has MD5 signature c79ee91af08057dfc269ee212915801a and is 1,462,376 bytes in size. What does your copy look like?

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this and get back to you with an answer.